# Python Pandas: Aggregate changed from 0.7.1 to 0.7.3

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

For some reason a script I wrote and worked with 0.7.1 did not work with 0.7.3

I reverted to 0.7.1 and everything worked fine. The problem seems to be with the aggregate method. I'm using a dictionary of different aggregation methods to `agg` different columns (`np.mean`, `np.sum`...etc). When running with 0.7.3 this threw a

> ```
> "No numeric values to aggregate"
> ```

error.

Any thoughts on this? I would like to get everything working in the 0.7.3 version... maybe some syntax changed?

Comment: Could you please post a runnable example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: I've actually not been able to recreate (I am reading from a database...when I recreate example with a random DF...I don't get the error). Also wrote the DF that was throwing the error to_csv then created a new script that read it in and then grouped...no error. Thanks for the help...sorry I can't be more helpful, pandas has been really useful so far!!